# Create pause link for clappr player

Tags: javascript, clappr

I am trying to stop the clappr player from playing via a link.  I have this code in the html of the page where my player is...

dev tools says that player.stop is not a function but I know it is a function in the clappr.js file which is in included and working.

any suggestion?

```
<script>
function timeOutVideo() {
this.player.stop();
}
</script>

<button onclick="timeOutVideo()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using a button then?

Comment: The point is to be able to send either the "stop" or "pause" command to the player... the button element is just for testing... because it's easy to type <button...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your video embedded from "YouTube"?
this function will stop it

```
$(function(){
$('yourbutton').click(function(){      
    $('iframeYoutube').attr('src', $('iframeYoutub').attr('src'));
});});
```

Comment: No, the video is not from youtube.  The video is live HLS video using CLAPPR Player.

Comment: Try: function togglePlay() { return player.isPlaying() ? player.pause() : player.play(); }

Comment: I tried the code you supplied.  Dev tools says Type Error - player.isPlaying is not a function.    The problem is it says that about every built in clappr function I use.   Somehow my javascript is not "seeing" the clappr js files or something...